# Difficulty passing struct through pthread_create

Tags: c, struct, pthreads, createthread

I have an array of structs and I intend to pass each element of the array into separate pthreads in a for loop.

Here's my struct:

```
struct arrayData{
int *a;
int *b;
int up, low;
}
```

Here's the pointer to the first struct and a malloc (don't know if I quite get what goes on here):

```
struct arrayData * instance;
        instance = malloc(sizeof(struct arrayData)*n);
```

Here's my call to pthread_create:

```
pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, add, (void *)instance[i]);
```

And for that line I'm getting the message "Cannot convert to a pointer type".

What could be wrong with that line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to convert a struct to a pointer in the last parameter. You need to pass the the struct's address with `&`.

```
pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, add, &instance[i]);
```

As jørgensen [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9914127/774071), the `void *` cast is unnecessary.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Need to hit the books on C this summer as I'm way too rusty. Why might I still be getting a warning for that line which says "Passing argument 3 of 'pthread-create' from incompatible pointer type."?

Comment: What's the signature of your `add` function?

Comment: Excellent! Can you explain to me why this guy didn't have to do that in this tutorial: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html

Comment: @mteckert: this is not needed in C. In fact, using `&` for function pointers makes it impossible to do preprocessor-time substitutions (`#define add NULL` -- not that NULL is useful for pthread_create, but it is in other situations).

Comment: @Chucky where have you declared `add`?

Answer (score 2):

`instance` is of type `struct arrayData *`, hence `instance[i]` is of type `struct arrayData`, which is an aggregate, not a pointer. Intended use was probably

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, add, &instance[i]);
```

The cast, btw, is pointless.